# How to improve this animation by use of scale and transform-origin while having font-size defined in pixel and at the same time forcing line breaks?

Tags: css, css-animations, css-transitions, css-transforms

I stumbled upon a problem. I have put an overlay over a video and inside this overlay I am animating a headline by scale, color and padding. The animation is causing a line break in the headline which is totally okay for me, because **I want the animation to appear totally centered and actually break the words so it is entirely visible**. That is why I use transform-origin. Nevertheless, it seems to me that in any browser the animation gets much quirkier. I fear it is bad code but I cant figure out what I have done wrong.

You might wonder why I stuck to font-size in percent so far. That´s why I need the headline to break to be readable in the overlays. So far when I define the font-size in pixels, the scale cuts the headline to the left and right. Though, apparently, when using pixel for font size the animations seems much more fluid. I find this to be contradictive as one would usually suppose to end up with a much quirkier animation defining font-size in pixels. Is there a better approach you can think of?

**Edit: I just added a Fiddle! https://jsfiddle.net/Schwark/nmdg24bq/20/
**

I appreciate any constructive input! Happy new year!

```
video {width: 100%;
  -webkit-filter: contrast(50%) brightness(110%) saturate(75%) sepia(82%);
  filter: contrast(50%) brightness(110%) saturate(75%) sepia(82%);
     }


.overlay-desc {
  z-index:8;
  opacity:1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.overlay-desc h4 {
  font-family: "Playfair Display", serif;
  font-weight: lighter;
  font-size:175%;
  border-top: 1px solid #595959;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #595959;
  padding-top:20px;
  padding-bottom:20px;
  color:#fff;
  -webkit-filter: contrast(50%) brightness(110%) saturate(75%) sepia(82%);
  filter: contrast(50%) brightness(110%) saturate(75%) sepia(82%);
  transform-origin: center center;  /* seems to make animation quirky, why? runs smoother when left out but does not accordingly center the animation in the video overlay */
   -webkit-transition: all 1.2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition:  all 1.2s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 1.2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 1.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 1.2s ease-in-out;
}

.overlay-desc:hover h4 {
  font-size:375%;
  color:#000;
  padding-bottom:43px;
  padding-top:43px;
  -webkit-filter: contrast(50%) brightness(110%) saturate(75%) sepia(82%);
  filter: contrast(50%) brightness(110%) saturate(75%) sepia(82%);
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.8);
  -moz-transform: scale(0.8);
  -ms-transform: scale(0.8);
  -o-transform: scale(0.8);
  transform: scale(0.8);
  -webkit-transition: all 1.2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition:  all 1.2s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 1.2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 1.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 1.2s ease-in-out;
}
```

```
<div class="col-md-12 animate-box">
                            <a class="video-grid">
                                <video playsinline="playsinline" autoplay="autoplay" muted="muted" loop="loop">
    <source src="images/video/korkernte3.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="images/video/korkernte3.webm" type="video/webm" />
    <source src="images/video/korkernte3.ogv" type="video/ogg" />
  </video><div class="overlay-desc">
        <h4>Der älteste nachwachsende Rohstoff der Welt</h4>
     </div> 

                            </a>
                        </div>
```

EDIT: You might note that I am no more than a hobby programmer. I have serious problems describing the problem, but: if you take a look at the link given above: I want to make it happen just exactely as it is and behaves. I just have the feeling that the code generates conflicts in itself, and that it could be done with less code, and that this would probably also influence the fluency of the animation.